# psycopg and python3: casting retrieved data

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I am having a problem with Python3.4 and psycopg2. 
I can successfully cast statements that select everything or a single column, but not statements that target specific columns, e.g.:

```
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras


conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

''' This works! '''
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table;""")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print( row['colname'] )


''' This doesn't: it returns a KeyError'''
cursor.execute("""SELECT (colname, other_col) FROM table;""")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print ( row['colname'] )


''' This works'''
cursor.execute("""SELECT (colname) FROM table;""")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row['colname'])


''' This works: it returns lists instead of dicts, accessing by row[key] rises an error, accessing by row[int] doesn't '''
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table;""")
allrows = cursor.fetchall()
print ( allrows[0][1] )


''' This doesn't work: it returns rows as lists of form ['(val1, val2)']'''
cursor.execute("""SELECT (colname, other_col) FROM table;""")
allrows = cursor.fetchall()
print ( allrows[0][1] )
```

Does anyone know why this occurs and how I can get statements like SELECT (colname, other_col) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like it's a simple typo: SELECT columns need to be outside parenthesis.